# I need to understand the Conditional ternary statement

Tags: javascript

So I tried to change the code below into a ternary operator, but it gave me and undefined result. Please can someone explain to me where I went wrong and how to deal with it appropriately. T for thanks.

```
const plantNeedsWater = function (day) {
  /*if (day === 'Wednesday'){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }*/
  (day === 'Wednesday') ? true : false
  return
}

console.log(plantNeedsWater('Tuesday'));
```

Comment: return day === 'Wednesday', you should put linting

Comment: @EugenSunic Post that as an answer.

Comment: @Barmar are you serious...

Comment: Putting `return` on the wrong line is just a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function with a simple plain `return;` returns **`undefined`**, not a primitive **Boolean**.

Also, you don't need a ternary operator, simply return your evaluation

```js
const plantNeedsWater = function (day) {
  return day === 'Wednesday';
}

console.log(plantNeedsWater('Tuesday'));   // false
console.log(plantNeedsWater('Wednesday')); // true
```

or in an **ES5** fashion using **[Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with implicit return**:

```
const plantNeedsWater = (day) => day === 'Wednesday';
```

Otherwise, if you really must use the [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)  you could use it to return non-Boolean values:

```js
const plantNeedsWater = function (day) {
  return day === 'Wednesday' ? "yes" : "no";
}

console.log(plantNeedsWater('Tuesday'));   // "no"
console.log(plantNeedsWater('Wednesday')); // "yes"
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, you're right about that solution.
Much appreciated.

Comment: @nkadm You're welcome. It was really a typo... but hopefully you now got some more insight and solutions in your toolbox.